# Calcular a variância dos valores relacionado a um intervalo do grupo? No soft R

Tags: r

Exemplo tenho o banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
MES  RESP
1   4.67
1   5.11
2   5.22
2   4.99
3   4.60
3   5.39
4   4.98
4   5.29
5   5.82
5   5.01
6   5.90
6   4.22
7   4.40
7   4.69
```

Como faço para calcular a Variância, Média, Desvio Padrão entre os meses 2 a 4 e 6 a 7 juntos? ou seja a Variância, Média, Desvio Padrão do seguintes valores sem ter que excluir nada do banco de dados

```
MES  RESP
2   5.22
2   4.99
3   4.60
3   5.39
4   4.98
4   5.29
6   5.90
6   4.22
7   4.40
7   4.69
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que pede pode ser feito com funções da família `*apply`, depois de definida uma função para calcular as estatísticas de interesse.

```
estatisticas <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE){
  m <- mean(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  v <- var(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  s <- sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  c(Media = m, Var = v, DesvPadrao = s)
}
```

Como só são necessárias as linhas da base com mês `MES` de 2 a 4 e 6 ou 7, cria-se uma sub-base com essas linhas.

```
dados2 <- subset(dados, MES %in% c(2:4, 6:7))
```

Primeiro vou calcular as estatísticas para cada valor do `MES`.

```
res <- tapply(dados2$RESP, dados2$MES, FUN = estatisticas)
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
res
#  Media     Var DesvPadrao
#2 5.105 0.02645  0.1626346
#3 4.995 0.31205  0.5586144
#4 5.135 0.04805  0.2192031
#6 5.060 1.41120  1.1879394
#7 4.545 0.04205  0.2050610
```

Agora, calcular as mesmas estatísticas por grupos de `MES`, um de 2 a 4 e o outro 6 ou 7.

```
grupo <- dados2$MES %in% 6:7
res2 <- tapply(dados2$RESP, grupo, FUN = estatisticas)
res2 <- do.call(rbind, res2)
row.names(res2) <- c(paste(2:4, collapse = "."), paste(6:7, collapse = "."))
res2
#         Media        Var DesvPadrao
#2.3.4 5.078333 0.08165667  0.2857563
#6.7   4.802500 0.57282500  0.7568520
```